# Does a player always has to have uncompleted destination tickets on-hand?

Tags: ticket-to-ride, ticket-to-ride-europe

When you finish your routes, do you have to draw new ones?

Answer (score 10):

No.

If you *do* complete all your routes, it is often a good idea to collect more since each route completed adds to your score, however this is very dependent on the current game situation (how many routes are free, how close it is to game end, how flexible your current rail system is) as you also risk drawing new cards that you *can't* complete and which would penalize you. However, there is nothing mandating that you always have tickets to complete: Since the contents of your tickets is not public information nobody should know that you've completed all your tickets until game end, so such a rule would be mostly unenforceable anyway.

According to the rules, the game turn consists of taking one (and only one) of the following four actions:

- Draw Train Car Cards
- Claim a Route
- Draw Destination Tickets
- Build a Train Station

However, there is absolutely nothing in the rules which tells you to take one of these actions over the others in any situation: It is entirely your choice as to which of the four actions to take.

Literally the only case I can conceive of where you'd be forced to collect more destination tickets (aside from the ones drawn during game setup) would be if the other three actions were, for whatever reason, unavailable to you. This would basically mean that there are (a) no train cards to draw, (b) you can't afford to claim any routes, and (c) you've already deployed your station. And if this does happen to you, you've probably already lost.

Comment: I wouldn't force a person to draw destination cards in that situation either.

Comment: @ikegami The rules specifically state that if no train cards are available to draw, the player must take one of the other three actions. I would assume from this that if building a station and claiming a route were not viable actions you would still have to perform the last possible action open to you: draw destinations. However I would consider it horrible sportsmanship if the other players were to hoard all the train cards just to force me to draw multiple unwanted destinations.

Comment: Yes, I know. And like I said, I wouldn't force a person to draw destination cards in that situation either. Rewarding someone for hogging all the cards can't possibly be what the designers envisioned. (All this is assuming it's actually possible to get into that situation, but that may be impossible.)